# Is there a way to edit Google Documents with Android

Tags: google-drive

Is there a way to edit Google documents from an Android device?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can now edit Google Docs with our mobile with the [official App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.docs) :)

More information can be found [in this blog](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2010/11/editing-your-google-docs-on-go.html) entry from the [official Google Documents blog](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 5):

There are apps out there now that should make it easier to use google docs on your phone but an official app will be out soon according to CNET news.

[Google Docs Coming to iPad, Android](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13506_3-20017086-17.html)

Answer (score 2):

I also found out this one as an alternative : http://sites.google.com/site/gdocsforandroid/

Answer (score 2):

[Documents to Go](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogo) has support for downloading, editing and syncing your Google Docs from your device. The initial sync is slow and saving to Google Docs sometimes fails, but support is there.